# Excel 2016: Nested IF Function "Too many arguments for this function"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering of you would be able to help me with a nested IF function problem I am having. Here is the question: (it's a long one sorry!)

- If the freight type is Victor Von Doom Freight then the freight cost is calculated at $4.50 per kilogram of the item weight and a quarter of a cent ($0.0025) per kilometer (distance) if over 1,000km per item ordered (Order Qty).
- If the freight type is Otto Octavis Transport then the freight cost is $10 for the first 1.5 kilograms and then $2.50 per kilogram over 1.5kg per item ordered (Order Qty).

**I also must include ROUNDING to 2 decimal places

So basically I have my IF statement as follows:

> IF(FreightType="Victor Von Doom
>   Freight", ROUND((4.5*ItemWeight+IF(Distance>1000,0.0025*Distance,"0"))*OrderQty,2), IF(FreightType="Otto
>   Octavius
>   Transport", ROUND((10+IF(ItemWeight>1.5, (ItemWeight-1.5)*2.5,"0"))*OrderQty,2),"0")

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently is incomplete. If you reformat it you can also write it like this:

```
IF
(
    FreightType="Victor Von Doom Freight"
    ,ROUND
        (
            (
                4.5*ItemWeight + 
                IF
                (
                    Distance>1000
                    ,0.0025*Distance
                    ,"0"
                )
            )
            *OrderQty
            ,2
        )
    ,IF
        (
            FreightType="Otto Octavius Transport"
            ,ROUND
                (
                    (
                        10+
                        IF
                        (
                            ItemWeight>1.5
                            ,(ItemWeight-1.5)*2.5
                            ,"0"
                        )
                    )
                    *OrderQty
                    ,2
                )
            ,"0"
        )
```

Which shows you're missing a closing bracket. Just adding one closing bracket to the end of it should make it work.

Comment: i only realised you could enter line breaks and spaces into a formula a few weeks back, after spending about 4 years using excel !

Comment: I got this to work, although I found it a lot less confusing to just have all the data for the feright costs in a seperate table and referacne those cells. Also means it's easier to make edits if their shipping charges change.

Comment: @User91504 Personally I'd probably not use them within Excel but if you're trying to debug it, it can be rather nice to figure out whenever your brackets are correct.